# Line decoder output changes when the initial clock value changes

Tags: decoder

I have been trying to code a fm0 decoder. Since the incoming data changes at both negedge and posedge of the CLK, to successfully decode the data, I need to sample the incoming data at the middle of the CLK. When I sample the middle of the data using always@(posedge CLK) i do get correct output, but when i change the initial value of CLK the output changes. Is there anyway to make the output stable.

Here the issue is that, even though I change the initial CLK value from tb, the incoming data always comes at 20ns. Is there any way to delay the input signal according to the CLK value?